# How to curl ingress in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

If host is * in ingress resource, how do I curl path?
use Nginx Ingress Controller

```
curl -kL <ingress-ip>/path
curl -kL <controller-service-ip>/path
curl -kL <node-ip>/path
Is only curl -kL /path possible?
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not told what Ingress implementation you are using. Some ingress services even run outside of Kubernetes so there is no generic answer except running `kubectl describe ingress <my-ingress>` then curl whatever address it shows.